# How replace two double quotes with a \" in Python?

Tags: python, string, escaping

This is my string,

```
"Alexandra ""Alex"""
```

I am trying to replace two adjacent double quotes with a /" so the result is something like this.

```
"Alexandra \"Alex\""
```

After this, I will append this string to an array. This looks very trivial, and I am able to do this with replace.

```
a = '"Alexandra ""Alex"""' 
x = a.replace('""', "\\\"")
print x
# prints "Alexandra \"Alex\""
res = []
res.append(x)
print res
# prints ['"Alexandra \\"Alex\\""']
```

When appending to another array it's escaping the forward slash again.

How can I remove the extra forward slash?

Comment: That's just the way it formats printing the list. The string isn't modified when it is appended. Also, that's a backslash.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara So how can i replace the double quotes to /" then ?

Comment: @Ilja Everilä Can you remove the duplicate, the question is now more on how to replace the double quote with a /"